# Delete the user from the List : Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

Can somebody help me to delete data of user list
Code is available below https://codesandbox.io/s/r4try
Please tell me how to delete particular user from the user list. please use delete button on user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/control-between-forms-ant-design-demo-99sus?file=/index.js)

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/control-between-forms-ant-design-demo-99sus?file=/index.js


<Form.Item
     label="User List"
            shouldUpdate={(prevValues, curValues) => prevValues.users !== curValues.users}
          >
            {({ getFieldValue, setFieldsValue }) => {
              const users = getFieldValue('users') || [];
              return users.length ? (
                <ul>
                  {users.map((user, index) => (
                    <li key={index} className="user">
                      <Avatar icon={<UserOutlined />} />
                      {user.name} - {user.age}
                      <CloseOutlined onClick={() =>{
                        const updatedUsers = delete users[index];
                        setFieldsValue({users: updatedUsers})
                      }} style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}/>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              ) : (
                <Typography.Text className="ant-form-text" type="secondary">
                  ( <SmileOutlined /> No user yet. )
                </Typography.Text>
              );
            }}
          </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

after I have updated the code, this version should be workable, above code is not working.

```
<Form.Item
        label="User List"
        shouldUpdate={(prevValues, curValues) => prevValues !== curValues}
      >
        {({ getFieldValue, setFieldsValue }) => {
          const users = getFieldValue("users") || [];
          return !!users.length ? (
            <ul>
              {users.map((user, index) => (
                <li key={index} className="user">
                  <Avatar icon={<UserOutlined />} />
                  {user?.name} - {user?.age}
                  <CloseOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      delete users[index];
                      const updatedUsers = users.filter((u) => !!u);
                      
                      setFieldsValue({ users: updatedUsers });
                    }}
                    style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}
                  />
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          ) : (
            <Typography.Text className="ant-form-text" type="secondary">
              ( <SmileOutlined /> No user yet. )
            </Typography.Text>
          );
        }}
      </Form.Item>
```

My trial: https://codesandbox.io/s/control-between-forms-ant-design-demo-forked-jd28v6?file=/index.js:2666-4129